# What is the directory /. for?

Tags: cmd, directory

I know that if you cd to /.. (from a command line, for example), you'll go up a directory. But when I run dir in a terminal I see the option "." as well as "..". What is the single-dot directory, and what purpose does it serve?

Very hard to search for this with search engines.

Comment: The single dot is a reference to the current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means "this directory."

In DOS/Windows it's seldom used, but in Linux it's frequently used. For example,

```
DOS: 
C:\Windows\System32> CD \
C:\> CD Temp
C:\Temp> dir
.
..
someprogram.exe
C:\Temp> someprogram
Hi, I'm someprogram...
```

And in Linux, note the ./ is required:

```
user@server user/me/temp/folder2: cd..
user@server user/me/temp: ls
someprogram
user@server user/me/temp: ./someprogram
Hi, I'm someprogram...
```